# Difference between "... me to show you" and "... you to show me"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I need to know the differences in meaning between this sentence and this question:

- Do you want me to show you?
- I want you to show me.

Comment: Other than that one is a statement and one is a question?

Comment: @Catija Haha, I was about to post the same. I think the OP asks why *want* is used like *want + subject + infinitive.*

Comment: yeah, but in the meaning that depend on the arrangement of pronouns and how this have changed the meaning?

Comment: Questions generally require some reordering of words... that's how they work... "Are you happy?" vs "You are happy."... or "When is lunch? vs "Lunch is at noon."

Comment: No, absolutely, the real difference that who shows the other one but I don't know how to explain the difference in meaning?

Answer (score 2):

> Do you want me to show you?

***Someone*** is asking if you want them to show you ***something***
*You are being asked if they can* ***push*** *you information*

> I want you to show me.

You are asking ***someone*** if they can show you ***something***
*You are asking to* ***pull*** *information*